# Tycho build Cohabiting with Eclipse RCP

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse, m2e, tycho

**The context**: I have embraced Eclipse Tycho to automate the build of my small clutch of plugins. It does a great job. Part of the Tycho migration included removing all Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files from SCM.

**The problem**: To work on my plugins in Eclipse I must import my projects using "Import => Existing Maven Project", however the resulting Eclipse project has a very different shape:

- It lacks any Eclipse plugins required to compile it
- though my sources lie in the usual directory `src/main/java` the project is not configured use this as a source directory.

**My question**: How can I build a `.project` and `.classpath` combination that will get me back to pre-Tycho IDE productivity.

- I have tried `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which says `"eclipse-plugin" no longer supported`, but does Tycho have something similar that is?
- `mvn clean install` builds successfully

Comment: m2e is the replacement for the maven-eclipse-plugin, do you have that installed already?  If not, might be something to try.

Comment: definitely check if you have m2e. On my Eclipse installation, the sources and dependencies are correctly set up from the POM.

Comment: The "Import" > "Existing Maven Project" UI is contributed by m2e, so obviously m2e is installed.

Comment: Does the project compile on the command line? I'm asking because if the Tycho configuration is broken, the import won't necessarily work.

Comment: Indeed it does - also answered in the question-body for clarity.

Comment: In general, m2eclipse prompts you to install a "Tycho configurator" when importing a Tycho project, and then imports Tycho projects correctly. So something is strange in your case. Maybe you have an outdated "Tycho configurator" installed. To be sure, you could uninstall it (*Help > Installation Details*) and re-import the Tycho project to trigger a fresh install of the configurator.

Comment: when you say:
It lacks any Eclipse plugins required to compile it.
 Have you set up a proper set of dependencies for your maven project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect the solution seems obvious, and my many thanks to `oberlies` for the clue.

To develop Eclipse plugins you **must** be using the Eclipse RCP/RAP edition or the Maven/Tycho import will **not** prompt you to install the Tycho configurator that maps the Maven project back into an Eclipse RCP project.

Repeating the steps outlined in my question, using "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" prompts the developer to install the configurator, after which Eclipse requires a restart, and leaves perfectly useful RCP plugins projects.

M.